# Posting a changed file: how to behave with the original authors name/email-address?

Tags: discussion

When I post on Stack Overflow a configuration file from a Linux distribution that I have modified, can I let the part where the original author is mentioned untouched or do I have to remove the original authors name/email-address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is usually not a bad idea to remove author information - it is not pertinent to the question.

You often want to post only the relevant parts of a file anyway.

In some cases however, technically, the license a file is published under might *require* you to leave the author info intact. It could also be that the license makes it entirely impossible to post the file on SO because it's incompatible with SO's CC-Wiki license.

You'll have to use your own judgement in these cases.